# Grid Game - Should I try and break this React component down?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, game-development

I'm having a go at creating a top down grid game as a way to learn react and test out my newly learned skills.

I have created a version that has some basic mechanics;
-click and dragging on cells within the grid to change their color.
-a player represented by a colored grid cell whose movement is controlled using the directional keys
-an automated bot represented by a colored grid cell that moves in random directions.

Now that my application is getting bigger I've noticed the code is getting harder to follow, before things get out of hand I want to break things down into smaller chunks but I'm encountering problems as many of the functions and useEffects require access to the same useState variables which makes putting them into separate js files impossible.

Key questions?

- Should I be trying to use useContext for useState variables?
- Would this even allow functions/useEffects kept in a separate .js utilities file to access said variables or is does it only work with components?
- Do I even need to break the code up and move functions/effects to separate js files? or is this some concept that I've miss understood when really is actually about components.

All efforts to modularise my code have failed due to the spaghetti use of variables.

Any pointers or help would be appreciated, cheers

```
  function BotTech() {

  const numRows = 20;
  const numCols = 20;

  const gridStyles = {
    display: "grid",
    gridTemplateRows: `repeat(${numRows}, 1fr)`,
    gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${numCols}, 1fr)`,
    gap: "0px", // Adjust the gap between cells if needed
    border: "1px solid black", // Optional border for each cell
    width: "800px",
  };

  const sectionStyle = {
    width: "100vw",
    height: "91vh",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  };

  const [mousePressed, setMousePressed] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {

    const handleGlobalMouseUp = () => {
      setMousePressed(false);
    };
    
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleGlobalMouseUp);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mouseup", handleGlobalMouseUp);
    };

  }, [])

  const [grid, setGrid] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    const newGrid = [];
    const cellStyles = {
      width: "40px", // Adjust cell size if needed
      height: "40px",
      backgroundColor: "grey", // Default cell background color
      border: "1px solid black",
    };

    for (let row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
      for (let col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
        newGrid.push({
          key: `${row}-${col}`,
          style: { ...cellStyles },
        });
      }
    }
    setGrid(newGrid);

  }, []);

  const [position, setPosition] = useState(`0-0`);

  const changeCellStyle = (key, color) => {
    setGrid((prevGrid) =>
      prevGrid.map((cell) =>
        cell.key === key
          ? { ...cell, style: { ...cell.style, backgroundColor: color } }
          : cell
      )
    );
  };

  const movePlayerUp = () => {
  const [first, second] = position.split("-").map(Number);
  const newPosition = `${first - 1}-${second}`;
  setPosition(newPosition);
  changeCellStyle(newPosition, "green");
  changeCellStyle(position, "grey");
  
  };

  const movePlayerDown = () => {
  const [first, second] = position.split("-").map(Number);
  const newPosition = `${first + 1}-${second}`;
  setPosition(newPosition);
  changeCellStyle(newPosition, "green");
  changeCellStyle(position, "grey");
  };

  const movePlayerLeft = () => {
  const [first, second] = position.split("-").map(Number);
  const newPosition = `${first}-${second - 1}`;
  setPosition(newPosition);
  changeCellStyle(newPosition, "green");
  changeCellStyle(position, "grey");
  };

  const movePlayerRight = () => {
  const [first, second] = position.split("-").map(Number);
  const newPosition = `${first}-${second + 1}`;
  setPosition(newPosition);
  changeCellStyle(newPosition, "green");
  changeCellStyle(position, "grey");
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
      switch (event.key) {
        case "ArrowUp":
          movePlayerUp();
          break;
        case "ArrowDown":
          movePlayerDown();
          break;
        case "ArrowLeft":
          movePlayerLeft();
          break;
        case "ArrowRight":
          movePlayerRight();
          break;
        default:
          // Handle other key presses if needed
          break;
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);

    // Cleanup the event listener when the component unmounts
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
    };
  }, );

  const [botPosition, setBotPosition] = useState(`10-10`);

  const moveBotUp = (botPosition) => {
    const [first, second] = botPosition.split("-").map(Number);
    const newBotPosition = `${first - 1}-${second}`;
    setBotPosition(newBotPosition);
    changeCellStyle(newBotPosition, "red");
    changeCellStyle(botPosition, "grey");
  };
  
  const moveBotDown = (botPosition) => {
    const [first, second] = botPosition.split("-").map(Number);
    const newBotPosition = `${first + 1}-${second}`;
    setBotPosition(newBotPosition);
    changeCellStyle(newBotPosition, "red");
    changeCellStyle(botPosition, "grey");
  };
  
  const moveBotLeft = (botPosition) => {
    const [first, second] = botPosition.split("-").map(Number);
    const newBotPosition = `${first}-${second - 1}`;
    setBotPosition(newBotPosition);
    changeCellStyle(newBotPosition, "red");
    changeCellStyle(botPosition, "grey");
  };
  
  const moveBotRight = (botPosition) => {
    const [first, second] = botPosition.split("-").map(Number);
    const newBotPosition = `${first}-${second + 1}`;
    setBotPosition(newBotPosition);
    changeCellStyle(newBotPosition, "red");
    changeCellStyle(botPosition, "grey");
  };

  const moveFunctions = [
    moveBotUp,
    moveBotDown,
    moveBotLeft,
    moveBotRight
  ];

  const randomMove = (position) => {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * moveFunctions.length);
    const selectedMoveFunction = moveFunctions[randomIndex];
    selectedMoveFunction(position);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const randomMoveInterval = setInterval(() => {
      randomMove(botPosition);
    }, 100); // Call a random move every 1000ms (1 second)

    return () => {
      clearInterval(randomMoveInterval);
    };
  }, [botPosition]);

  const handleMouseDown = (key) => {
    changeCellStyle(key, "blue");
    setMousePressed(true);
  };

  const handleMouseOver = (key) => {
    if (mousePressed) {
      changeCellStyle(key, "blue");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={sectionStyle}>
      <h1>{position}</h1>
      <div style={gridStyles}>
        {grid.map((cell) => (
          <div
            key={cell.key}
            style={cell.style}
            onMouseDown={() => handleMouseDown(cell.key)}
            onMouseOver={() => handleMouseOver(cell.key)}
          ></div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
  }

  export default BotTech
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Here is my take

### State:

When it comes to state there are two maybe three options

1. Pass it down through props
2. useContext hook
3. *Rare case but...* Build a separate component to manage the state

#### How do I know when to use what?

Generally, it's up to you some people won't prop drill(*passing props down multiple components*) more than one component. And that might be the correct answer however my rule is I won't go more than two levels down. So if you are passing a value down more than two components I would switch to use context before things get messy.

### Functions

Your functions can definitely be put in a different folder. I would name it **utils** or maybe name the folder specifical for the board like **board-utils**. Once you export the functions using export syntax you will be cleaning up the code a lot.

#### Can I make it a function?

A function can take in any value(s) and return a value so if you keep this in mind you will find that lots of things can be reduced to functions. For example, there is nothing stopping you from passing a state variable into a function and altering it, and returning another value.

- *Hope this helps give you a start*

Comment: Thanks very much for the comment. 

My problem is that whenever I try to move any function it seems like the function needs at a state variable that at least one other function needs. If I move the declaration of state variable, one or the other function cant access it. Do I need to pass the state variables and setters into the functions as arguments when they are called? Same as prop drilling but with functions...kind of? I guess it doesn't help that I'm doing this retrospectively

Whenever I feel like I've finally clicked with react something else pops up that makes me think otherwise.

Comment: Yes you can pass a ```theState``` and `setTheState` into the function as params. the setState function will always cause a re-render when called to change a value

Comment: Thanks, I think passing theState and setTheState into the function as params is the thing I was not seeing (I am new to coding) and then I mistakenly though useContext is what I needed but this is actually for a different situation although it does use a similar concept .

Comment: Happy to help! You should probably up an answer if you accepted it :) Just letting you know since you are new.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to do that unfortunately